# Echo in sound with WebRTC Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am doing live stream between two Android devices with WebRTC. Sometimes, with some users, there is echo in sound. I use hands-free (speaker) on both end.

So how can I remove the echo? Maybe I did something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first try to check if the echo is also there when using WhatsApp. If it is, the echo is related to the device and probably difficult to fix.

If not, it could be related to the audio mode. Make sure to set the audio mode to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` when the call is established:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

Comment: thanks jeyhey ! no using whatsapp their is no echo! I will try asp the MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

Comment: didn't yet test it :( already implemented but need to deploy the app to test it !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
if (!isSpeakerphoneOn)
{
    audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(null);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
} 
else
{
    audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
}
```