# Android echo cancellation with libaudiopreprocessing

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, microphone, aec

we have a board with a RK3399 Android9 where we have modify the audio_effects.xml as here below for have the audio echo cancellation (AEC) enabled by default on the system.
However the device when is in call seems to no apply the AEC. We have read this post and tried to add this line audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION); to our app only for test
[Acoustic Echo Cancellation on Android not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429987/acoustic-echo-cancellation-on-android-not-working) but nothing change.

There is the possibility to enable the WEBRTC AEC by default on the system and left enabled without the necessity that the app enable that? We need a system AEC always enabled.

THanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<audio_effects_conf version="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/audio/audio_effects_conf/v2_0">
    <!-- List of effect libraries to load.
         Each library element must contain a "name" attribute and a "path" attribute giving the
         name of a library .so file in /vendor/lib/soundfx on the target

         If offloadable effects are present, the AOSP library libeffectproxy.so must be listed as
         well as one library for the SW implementation and one library for the DSP implementation:
         <library name="proxy" path="libeffectproxy.so"/>
         <library name="some_fx_sw" path="lib_some_fx_sw.so"/>
         <library name="some_fx_hw" path="lib_some_fx_hw.so"/>

         If the audio HAL implements support for AOSP software audio pre-processing effects,
         the following library must be added:
         <library name="pre_processing" path="libaudiopreprocessing.so"/>
    -->
    <libraries>
        <library name="bundle" path="libbundlewrapper.so"/>
        <library name="reverb" path="libreverbwrapper.so"/>
        <library name="visualizer" path="libvisualizer.so"/>
        <library name="downmix" path="libdownmix.so"/>
        <library name="loudness_enhancer" path="libldnhncr.so"/>
        <library name="dynamics_processing" path="libdynproc.so"/>
        <library name="pre_processing" path="libaudiopreprocessing.so"/>
    </libraries>

    <!-- list of effects to load.
         Each "effect" element must contain a "name", "library" and a "uuid" attribute.
         The value of the "library" element must correspond to the name of one library element in
         the "libraries" element.
         The "name" attribute is indicative, only the value of the "uuid" attribute designates
         the effect.
         The uuid is the implementation specific UUID as specified by the effect vendor. This is not
         the generic effect type UUID.

         Offloadable effects are described by an "effectProxy" element which contains one "libsw"
         element containing the "uuid" and "library" for the SW implementation and one "libhw"
         element containing the "uuid" and "library" for the DSP implementation.
         The "uuid" value for the "effectProxy" element must be unique and will override the default
         uuid in the AOSP proxy effect implementation.

         If the audio HAL implements support for AOSP software audio pre-processing effects,
         the following effects can be added:
         <effect name="agc" library="pre_processing" uuid="aa8130e0-66fc-11e0-bad0-0002a5d5c51b"/>
         <effect name="aec" library="pre_processing" uuid="bb392ec0-8d4d-11e0-a896-0002a5d5c51b"/>
         <effect name="ns" library="pre_processing" uuid="c06c8400-8e06-11e0-9cb6-0002a5d5c51b"/>
    -->

    <effects>
        <effect name="bassboost" library="bundle" uuid="8631f300-72e2-11df-b57e-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="virtualizer" library="bundle" uuid="1d4033c0-8557-11df-9f2d-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="equalizer" library="bundle" uuid="ce772f20-847d-11df-bb17-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="volume" library="bundle" uuid="119341a0-8469-11df-81f9-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="reverb_env_aux" library="reverb" uuid="4a387fc0-8ab3-11df-8bad-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="reverb_env_ins" library="reverb" uuid="c7a511a0-a3bb-11df-860e-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="reverb_pre_aux" library="reverb" uuid="f29a1400-a3bb-11df-8ddc-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="reverb_pre_ins" library="reverb" uuid="172cdf00-a3bc-11df-a72f-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="visualizer" library="visualizer" uuid="d069d9e0-8329-11df-9168-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="downmix" library="downmix" uuid="93f04452-e4fe-41cc-91f9-e475b6d1d69f"/>
        <effect name="loudness_enhancer" library="loudness_enhancer" uuid="fa415329-2034-4bea-b5dc-5b381c8d1e2c"/>
        <effect name="dynamics_processing" library="dynamics_processing" uuid="e0e6539b-1781-7261-676f-6d7573696340"/>
        <effect name="agc" library="pre_processing" uuid="aa8130e0-66fc-11e0-bad0-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="aec" library="pre_processing" uuid="bb392ec0-8d4d-11e0-a896-0002a5d5c51b"/>
        <effect name="ns" library="pre_processing" uuid="c06c8400-8e06-11e0-9cb6-0002a5d5c51b"/>
    </effects>

    <!-- Audio pre processor configurations.
         The pre processor configuration is described in a "preprocess" element and consists in a
         list of elements each describing pre processor settings for a given use case or "stream".
         Each stream element has a "type" attribute corresponding to the input source used.
         Valid types are:
              "mic", "camcorder", "voice_recognition", "voice_communication"
         Each "stream" element contains a list of "apply" elements indicating one effect to apply.
         The effect to apply is designated by its name in the "effects" elements.

        <preprocess>
            <stream type="voice_communication">
                <apply effect="aec"/>
                <apply effect="ns"/>
            </stream>
        </preprocess>
    -->
    <preprocess>
      <stream type="voice_communication">
        <apply effect="aec"/>
        <apply effect="ns"/>
      </stream>
     
      <stream type="camcorder">
        <apply effect="agc"/>
      </stream>
    </preprocess>
      

    <!-- Audio post processor configurations.
         The post processor configuration is described in a "postprocess" element and consists in a
         list of elements each describing post processor settings for a given use case or "stream".
         Each stream element has a "type" attribute corresponding to the stream type used.
         Valid types are:
              "music", "ring", "alarm", "notification", "voice_call"
         Each "stream" element contains a list of "apply" elements indicating one effect to apply.
         The effect to apply is designated by its name in the "effects" elements.

        <postprocess>
            <stream type="music">
                <apply effect="music_post_proc"/>
            </stream>
            <stream type="voice_call">
                <apply effect="voice_post_proc"/>
            </stream>
            <stream type="notification">
                <apply effect="notification_post_proc"/>
            </stream>
        </postprocess>
        
    -->
  
</audio_effects_conf>
```