# AOSP Audio Echo Cancellation with libaudiopreprocessing

Tags: android, webrtc, android-source, aec

We have an Android9 environment, where we want to have echo cancellation enabled by default. A similar question was already made once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581079/android-echo-cancellation-with-libaudiopreprocessing), but no answer was given.

We have developed a WebRTC App with a SIP Client included and we have a huge echo problem.

How can I enable echo cancellation by default in the system, on any channel. We need a system AEC always enabled. The /vendor/etc/audio_effects.xml looks like this:

> <audio_effects_conf version="2.0" xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/audio/audio_effects_conf/v2_0">
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> `your text`
>
> </audio_effects_conf>

We tried different audio_effects configurations. The lib libqcomvoiceprocessing.so was also exchanged...without any change.

Comment: If you are on a qualcomm device? (suggested by libqcomvoiceprocessing.so) , you might need to enable Qualcomm FLUENCE in the Qualcomm Audio HAL from the BSP. This should help you add support for AEC (Acoustic Echo Cancellation)